# I am not able to display error messages in a form that uses names

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make it so that when fields are empty, an error message should display on clicking the submit button, telling the user to fill it. However, not a single error message displays.
I want to display the error message in a paragraph below the form, and not through an alert.

I have checked that the variables do in fact hold the correct information, using a simple alert(variableName), however I have not been able to display errors using either alerts or .innerHTML
Although, I am unable to get a value for the drop-down list.

This is the HTML:

```
<!-- This is for the name -->
        <p>Name: 
          <input type="text" name="textfield"> 
          </p>
<!-- This is for the email -->
      <p align="left" class="style3">E-mail: 
        <input type="text" name="textfield">
</p>
<!-- This is for the type of bird -->
      <p align="left" class="style3">Bird: 
        <select name="select" size="1">
          <option>Rainbow Lorikeet</option>
          <option>Golden Pheasant</option>
          <option selected>Hoopoe</option>
          <option>Bird of Paradise</option>
          <option>Kingfisher</option>
          <option>Peacock</option>
          <option>Other</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="textfield">
</p>
<!-- This is for location of bird -->
      <p align="left" class="style3">Location: 
        <input type="text" name="textfield"></p>
      <p align="left" class="style3">You must agree to us contacting you to find out about your sighting. Please tick this box to agree to this statement: 
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox">
</p>
      <p align="left" class="style3">
        <input onclick='checking()' type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</p>
<p id='output'></p>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
function checking() {
        var name = document.getElementsByName('textfield')[0]
        var email = document.getElementsByName('textfield')[1]
        var otherBird = document.getElementsByName('textfield')[2]
        var location = document.getElementsByName('textfield')[3]
        var birdSelect = document.getElementsByName('select')[0]
        var bird = birdSelect.options[birdSelect.selectedIndex]
        if (name.value===null){
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Please enter your name'
            return false
        } else if (email.value===null) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Please enter your email'
            return false
        } else if (location.value===null) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Please enter the location of the bird'
            return false
        } else if (otherBird.value===null && bird.text==='Other') {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Please enter a bird's name"
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

An error message should be displayed when:

  -
  **textfield[0]**
  (Name),
  **textfield[1]**
  (Email) or
  **textfield[3]**
  (Location) are empty.

  -
  **textfield[2]**
  (Other Bird) is empty when, and only when, the value of
  **select**
  is "Other"

  - The value of
  **checkbox**
  is false (although I do not know how to do this and thus have not tried it)

If you need something to be clarified, I will be happy to do so.
Thank you in advance

Comment: `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Please enter your name'` - error message is inserted here, but I don't see element with id `output` in your html code.

Comment: @1_bug it's at the very bottom of the first snippet. I must say I'm confused by the fact that this is different from the last snippet, which the OP says cannot be changed? We need to know which HTML is actually being used, because that in the last snippet definitely won't work.

Comment: *"This is the HTML"* ... and ... *"This is the source"* - Which is it?

Comment: When posting a question here, you should include in it only the relevant code, to make clear which is your point. Usually, the bigger the code attached to question is, the less answers you will get... :-(

Comment: What's the point of using the same input `name`?

Comment: The last block of code was the file I was handed. The other two were me trying to solve the task I was given. I am not allowed to change the source, but merely add to it.

Comment: @NeelKallidai: So what does the last block of code have to do with the other two?  What is the exact and actual code you're using?

Comment: @David I thought it would be better for context to add the source. Should I remove it then?

Comment: @NeelKallidai: If it's unrelated to the question then, yes, it should be removed from the question.  If it *is* related then it should be clarified.

Comment: @Anakin Im not too sure myself. Im currently learning JavaScript in school. The teacher doesnt know Javascript, but its part of the syllabus. This was part of a worksheet given to me

Comment: @NeelKallidai By having the same `name` attribute, their value will override each other. To keep it simple, you need different names for each input for it to work. (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp)

Comment: @Anakin Yes, however i cannot change that since this is a task. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the values for **empty strings**, as demoed below:

```js
function check() {
  // clear output
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ''

  // check for null OR empty string
  var name = document.getElementsByName('textfield')[0]
  if (name.value === null || name.value === '') {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Please enter your name'
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Name: <input type="text" name="textfield">
  <input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Check">
</div>

Output:
<p id='output'></p>
```

Probably you can even omit the `null` comparison, still I left it in anyway.